# Encryption using multiple keys

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography

### Encryption using multiple keys

Let's say I have a file f that needs to be encrypted. I encrypt the file using a randomly generated key (using any encryption standard, say AES-256) and store this key in a key file k1. Now I encrypt k1 using another (different) randomly generated key and put this in file k2. I repeat this process to get kn-1 files. Now when I encrypt the file kn-1, I put the key (randomly generated) into file kn. So in kn, key to decrypt kn-1 is stored without any encryption and can be directly used to decrypt kn-1.
The decryption process is the opposite. The key file kn is used to decrypt kn-1, which is used to decrypt kn-2 and so on till k1 is decrypted. Key in k1 is used to decrypt the starting file f.

I am very new to encryptions so forgive me if this is a lame question but I had read somewhere about the merits and demerits of encrypting the same file multiple times and I thought of this. I have a few questions. What is this type of encryption called? I presume it could be used in a situation where there is file that is shared by n number of participants and should be opened only if all n participants are present at the same time, in which case, each of these n participants could be given a key and since the keys can only be opened sequentially, keys of each one would have to be present. Any other situations it can be used in?

Also, a major question is this - Can the decryption chain be bypassed somewhere? I mean to decrypt the kn file, you need the kn+1 file, so is there a way that I am missing that an attacker could access kn file without having kn+1 file? (I am assuming a strong encryption algorithm is used and brute forcing is not an option).

I am new to Stackoverflow so I apologize in advance if I have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: *"I presume it could be used in a situation where there is file that is shared by n number of participants"* - No, this is not a secret sharing scheme. There are other ways.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. [crypto.se] is much better suited for this type of question.